# Python regex for matching single line and multi line comments.

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a python regex, for PLY, which will match comments of the form

```
// some comment
```

and

```
/* comment
   more comment */
```

So I tried

```
t_COMMENT = r'//.+ | /\*.+\*/'
```

but this doesn't allow for multi line comments and when I try to solve this using the 'dot matches all' options like

```
t_COMMENT = r'//.+ | (?s) /\*.+\*/'
```

it results in the '//' comment type matching many lines. Also if I try to have two separate regexes like

```
t_COMMENT = r'//.+' 
t_COMMENT2 = r'(?s) /\*.+\*/'
```

the '//' comment type still matches multiple lines as though the dot matches all option is selected.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a BAD idea.  Trying to do too much high level (grammatical) parsing using complex regular expressions is the antithesis of creating a lexer/parser system.  I'd suggest that you have tokens for single line comment, and multi-line begin and end.  The grammar built around that parser can discard all input found between multi-line begin and end.

Comment: Can you give an answer based on your idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below regex would match both type of comments,

```
(?://[^\n]*|/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/4)

```
>>> s = """// some comment
... 
... foo
... bar
... foobar
... /* comment
...    more comment */ bar"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?://[^\n]*|/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/)', s, re.DOTALL)
>>> m
['// some comment', '/* comment\n   more comment */']
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a minor variation on Avinash's solution.

`pat = re.compile(r'(?://.*?$)|(?:/\*.*?\*/)', re.M|re.S)`

Answer (score 2):

According to [PLY Doc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn21) it can be accomplished with 'Conditional lexing'.
It might be more readable, and easier to debug, than complex regular expression.
The example they give is a little bit more complicated, since it keeps track of nesting levels, and the content inside the block. However, your case is simpler, since you don't need all that info.

The code for multi line comment should be something like this:

```
# I'd prefer 'multi_line_comment', but it appears that 
# state names cannot have underscore in them
states = (
    ('multiLineComment','exclusive'),
)

def t_multiLineComment_start(t):
    r'/\*'
    t.lexer.begin('multiLineComment')          

def t_multiLineComment_end):
    r'\*/'
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')           

def t_multiLineComment_newline(t):
    r'\n'
    pass

# catch (and ignore) anything that isn't end-of-comment
def t_multiLineComment_content(t):
    r'[^(\*/)]'
    pass
```

Of course, you'll have to have another rule, under the regular state, for `//` comments.

Answer (score 0):

This re maybe useful

```
 (/\*(.|\n)*?*/)|(//.*)
```